# TextInputLayout hint text color changing on focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Initially I set the text hint color to gray... If validation fails then changes hint color to red.. But if I move to another EditText(whenever lost the focus).. color is showing default..

Below is the code I used in layout

```
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tip_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_email"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/EditTextHint">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_email"
                    style="@style/EditTextWithBlackMediumSizeWithoutLeftAndTopPadding10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/label_input_color" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

styles I used to modify the color

```
 <style name="EditTextHint" parent="MyMaterialTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/label_input_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_mini</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">@bool/fletTextcaps</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextHintError" parent="MyMaterialTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_selected_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_mini</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">@bool/fletTextcaps</item>
</style>
```

Java code I used to change color is

```
tip_email.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.EditTextHintError);
```

tip_email.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.EditTextHintError);

Attached screenshots

[Starting Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvDBp.png)
[Email validation failed and color changed to red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IHfB.png)

I need color to be on same even focus has been changed..
Please suggest on this....

Comment: Did you find solution to this issue. I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Same here. Any acceptable solution?

Answer (score 2):

you can simply do that by using the material TextInputLayout and add textColorHint , hintTextColor attributes , this works perfectly

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/gray"
         
           >
```

Comment: This worked for me, especially when using the OutlinedBox style for textInputLayout. The `textColorHint` is used when the textInputLayout isn't focused why the `hintTextColor` is used to change the hint text color for when the textInputLayout is focused and the hint is at the top left of the box.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug in the `TextInputLayout` class. When you update the HintTextAppearance by calling `setHintTextAppearance` it only changes `mFocusedTextColor` and not the `mDefaultTextColor`.

You can check the source code: [TextInputLayout source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.java)

Solution with reflection, with changing the colors at the same time:

```
public void setInputTextLayoutColor(TextInputLayout til, @ColorInt int color) {
    try {
        final Field fDefaultTextColor = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mDefaultTextColor");
        fDefaultTextColor.setAccessible(true);
        fDefaultTextColor.set(til, new ColorStateList(new int[][]{{0}}, new int[]{color}));

        final Field fFocusedTextColor = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mFocusedTextColor");
        fFocusedTextColor.setAccessible(true);
        fFocusedTextColor.set(til, new ColorStateList(new int[][]{{0}}, new int[]{color}));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `defaultHintTextColor` on TextInputLayout to your desire color programmatically

```
val colorInt = resources.getColor(R.color.red)
val csl = ColorStateList.valueOf(colorInt)
tipEmail.defaultHintTextColor = csl
```